# How to append results as a matrix to a dataframe using functions in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I am working with these 2 dataframes

```
Datetime <- c("2016-01-20 08:30:13", "2016-01-20 12:45:00", "2016-01-20 02:53:20", "2016-01-20 03:22:18", "2016-01-20 21:42:10", 
              "2016-01-21 07:55:50", "2016-01-21 13:14:10", "2016-01-21 15:42:16", "2016-01-21 18:31:15", "2016-01-21 19:13:10")
Measurement <- c(10,120,180,30,240,40,300,380,960,390)
Outlier <- c("FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE")
Type <- c("Length","Length","Height","Breadth","Length",
          "Breadth","Breadth","Height","Height","Length" )
df <- data.frame(Datetime,Measurement,Outlier,Type)    
df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


Start <- c("2016-01-20 00:00:00","2016-01-21 00:00:00")
End <- c("2016-01-20 23:59:59","2016-01-21 23:59:59")
Days <- c("Day1","Day2")    
df2 <- data.frame(Start,End,Days)
```

I am trying to get a breakdown of the count of outliers by its type. I am trying to do it this way.

```
df_final <- data.frame(apply(df2, 1, function(d)
{
  df3 <- subset(df, Datetime >= as.POSIXct(d["Start"]) & Datetime <= as.POSIXct(d["End"]))
  df3_outliers <- subset(df3, Outlier=="TRUE")
  df3_outliers$Days <- d["Days"]

  df_breakdown <- dcast(df3_outliers,Days ~ Type,value.var="Days")

}))
```

This gives me

```
  Days Height Length Days.1 Breadth Height.1 Length.1
  Day1      1      2   Day2       1        2        1
```

But my **desired output** is

```
  Days Breadth Height Length    
  Day1      0    1      2 
  Day2      1    2      1
```

I know I am missing something very basic to get it as a matrix using the apply function but I am not sure where I am going wrong with this

Kindly provide some inputs and directions on solving this.

**EDIT:**

While David's answered worked for the above solution but I am in a slightly tricky situation here while applying David's logic to my bigger dataset.

*Here is the explanation:* (which I didn't really do it well earlier)
Firstly, I apologize for putting both the data for Day1 and Day2 in df. The df has 2 chunks of data (Day1 and Day2) which doesn't exist together like the above. df3 is what my data looks like after I run an outlier analysis for day1 which means that I won't be able to see the data for day2 (the last 5 rows in df) unless the program completes the outlier analysis for day1.  This is the reason I have used df3 as a subset dataframe.

```
              Datetime Measurement Outlier    Type
1  2016-01-20 08:30:13          10   FALSE  Length
2  2016-01-20 12:45:00         120    TRUE  Length
3  2016-01-20 02:53:20         180    TRUE  Height
4  2016-01-20 03:22:18          30   FALSE Breadth
5  2016-01-20 21:42:10         240    TRUE  Length
```

I then have to get the breakdown by type

```
      Days Breadth Height Length    
      Day1      0    1      2
```

I need to store this information in a dataframe and then run the outlier program for Day 2 and now df3 will have data only for Day2. So after the breakdown for Day2, I would like to append the result to Day1 as my final data frame.

I hope this is clear. Please let me know if it isn't.

*This is sort of a loop that keeps appending the breakdowns by day after every run and finally we obtain a dataframe with "Desired output".*

Comment: Do you really need `df2` or it just represents the days in `df` and you just trying to aggregate by day?

Comment: In such case you could simply do `library(data.table) ; dcast(setDT(df), as.Date(Datetime) ~ Type, subset = .(Outlier == "TRUE"))`

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for overlapping joins it seems, here's a possible `data.table::foverlaps` solution (I'm assuming `Start` and `End` are of `POSIXct` class in real life, rather factors)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df)[, c("Start", "End") := Datetime], Start, End)
dcast(foverlaps(setDT(df2), df[Outlier == "TRUE"], nomatch = 0L), Days ~ Type)
#    Days Breadth Height Length
# 1: Day1       0      1      2
# 2: Day2       1      2      1
```

Comment: David. Thanks for this wonderful solution. I realized I haven't explained my problem well and so I have added as an "EDIT" under my original question above. Please check that and see if that makes sense. I appreciate it.

Comment: Just run the code for each day as I shown in the comments under you question. Or use the below solution. They both should work per your edit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work for you.

```
library(sqldf)
library(reshape2)
df$Datetime <- format(as.Date(substr(df$Datetime,1,10)), format="%Y-%m-%d")
output <- sqldf("Select Datetime,Type,count(*) as CT from df where Outlier =    'TRUE' group by Datetime,Type")
dcast(output,Datetime~Type)
```

Comment: That's clever though you completely ignoring `df2`. I'm not sure if this will always work...